# How to trace an anonymous injected javascript code by malware

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security

Recently, my MacBook got infected by a malware. Randomly popping up ads on both Safari & Chrome. I tried several malware scanner, but all failed to clean the mess up. So I decided give it a try by myself.

What I find out is the malware injects a javascript tag into every loaded page, by using following code:

```
var js_script = document.createElement('script'); 
js_script.type = "text/javascript"; 
js_script.src = "XXXX"; // the malware ads js loader link
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js_script);
```

This code is dynamically injected after every web page is loaded. The Chrome developer tool gives something like "VM123:1" as its source tag. I think this exclude the possibility of network injection like DNS hi-jacking.

I also disabled all the extension in Chrome, which was the most and only suspicious invoker I can think of. But with no luck.

Any idea on how to proceed the trace?

Comment: Often on Windows I know they install themselves inside the Google chrome app folder. You could look through there, or just try and uninstall chrome and reinstall

Comment: I did. Nothing changed. The injection seems to come out of the browsers.